# subtract from previous row by current sas

Tags: loops, date, sas, sum

I am dealing with a repayment schedule and have something along the following format

I need to calculate the last row new_outstanding in sas?

by removing the amount outstanding from the previous row

I have done something along the lines of

```
  data want;
  set have;

 by perm_id
 if _n_=1 then remainder=total;
 remainder + -num ;
 run;
```

[see below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sD6e.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just made up some sample data, that resembles your posted data. See if this works for you.

```
data have;
input perm_id repayment outstanding;
datalines;
1 3 20 
1 3 20 
1 3 20 
2 5 50 
2 5 50 
2 5 50 
;

data want(drop = lag_:);
   set have;
   by perm_id;

   lag_repayment = lag(repayment);

   if first.perm_id then do;
      lag_repayment = .;
      new = outstanding;
   end;

   else new = sum(new, -lag_repayment);

   retain new;
run;
```

**Result:**

```
perm_id repayment outstanding new
1       3         20          20
1       3         20          17
1       3         20          14
2       5         50          50
2       5         50          45
2       5         50          40
```

Comment: Hi Peter , Thanks. I have one issue the amount outstanding increases say between the 4th and 5th one from 50 to say 60.? Cannot get an accurate result.

Comment: @John Seb So your OUTSTANDING is not a constant?  Then accumulate the repayments and then subtract the new cummulative repayments from the existing (cummuative) outstanding to get NEW balance due.

Comment: Hi Tom . Can’t do that as some of the payments rolls off . Ie decrease the the cumulative repayment is bigger than than outstanding . Needs to accumalate but with expiry roll off .

Comment: Then you need more data than the variables you are showing.

Comment: Ah yes you will have start and end dates will post below . I do believe it’s doable with that just doesn’t seem to run .

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following;

```
 data deal(drop = lag_:);
  set work.want;
  by perm_id;

  lag_repayment = lag(repayment);

  if first.perm_id then do;
  lag_repayment = .;
  new = tranche_amount;
 end;

 else new = sum(tranche_amount, sum(-lag_repayment);

 retain new;
run;
```